# Set td offSetWidth in a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am attempting to set the width of a table td element using javascript. When set outside of a function the width is set correctly. When the same code is encapsulated in a function, the width of the td element remains unchanged. I have inserted breakpoints and it appears the code is fired. Thank you for your help.

This works:

```
document.getElementById("myTD").offsetWidth = document.getElementById('<%= ID=myGridView.ClientID %>').rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth;
```

This does not:

```
function myfunction() { document.getElementById("myTD").offsetWidth = document.getElementById('<%= ID=myGridView.ClientID %>').rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth; };
```

The function is successfully called from code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(),
                "myfunction",
                "myfunction();",
                true);
    }
```

Comment: make sure you have the word `function` when declaring your myfunction in javascript. `function myfunction(){ //code }`

Comment: Good catch i do have function in my actual code however i did not include it in the example. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a scope issue, do I need to pass in the controls?

Answer (score 0):

So you've got javascript invoked by the server.  The big question is when is the script executed and when was your original script executed?  My guess is that your old script was executed after the page was loaded, so all elements referenced existed and all elements had been painted by the browser.

Your new script probably runs before the content is fully loaded, meaning the browser can't find a referenced element because it hasn't been loaded yet, or nothing has been painted so all the elements have no width.

Comment: You are correct the code when outside of the function is run when the page is loaded as it exists in the aspx markup ie: <script type="text/javascript"> some code and functions </script>.  When the function is executed from the Page_load Event from the behind code I can see using break points that the gridview widths have correct values however the td values remain unchanged. Could it be that the gridview is rendered but the table is not? I can see values for the tds as well but they are not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working however the TD element is slightly wider than the gridview element. I believe this has something to do with padding:

```
function MyFunction(){ document.getElementById("myTd").width = document.getElementById('<%= ID=myGridview.ClientID %>').rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth; };
```